# Bluetooth audio controls in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

My app streams music and I want to be able to pause/play/skip from any Bluetooth device that might support these buttons (car, headset, etc). When connected through a car's bluetooth the audio comes through automatically, but the control buttons do not affect my app's audio stream. It instead opens the default media player. How do I route these buttons to affect my app?

Comment: Hi, Can you share example code for this same ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have you registered a `BroadcastReceiver` in your app to listen to `MEDIA_BUTTON` events using [`AudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#registerMediaButtonEventReceiver%28android.content.ComponentName%29)?

After registering, the button events can be handled by processing the `KeyEvent` object attached in the extras as `EXTRA_KEY_EVENT`. For example:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
    if (event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) return;

    switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_STOP:
            // stop music
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE:
            // pause music
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT:
            // next track
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS:
            // previous track
            break;
    }
}
```

This [Android Developer blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/allowing-applications-to-play-nicer.html) also have some nice information on the subject.

Comment: I saw `MEDIA_BUTTON` events coming through the log, so this looks promising. I'll give it a go tomorrow.

Answer (score 6):

Further to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8074401/419), please be aware that one of the Keycodes has changed in Ice Cream Sandwich:

> The  keycode that gets passed for play/pause intent has changed in
>   ICS. See this
>   http://code.google.com/p/media-button-router/issues/detail?id=10#c5
>
> The keycode that had been sent prior to ICS was
>   KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE. Now there are two separate keycodes
>   for play and pause (126 and 127).

It's sending KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY (126) and KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE (127).

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23172

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this API has changed since the accepted answer was written. Please refer to the [MediaSession callbacks documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/mediasession-callbacks).